# grails JSON binding to LinkedHashSet instead of JSONArray for deeply nested relation

Tags: json, grails, data-binding

I have three levels deep of a hierarchy that I am binding in a JSON request:

```
Group -> Zone -> Segment
(1) -> (n) -> (n)
```

In my command object I have:

```
class GroupCommand {
    Long id 
    Set zones

}
```

When binding the JSON request the zones get bound properly and I get a LinkedHashSet that I can get the properties of and use with my domain object. However when I get to iterating over the segments in my service:

```
groupCommand.zones.each { zone -> 
    zone.segments.each { segment ->
        //Would like to get LinkedHashMap here also
        //but get JSONArray
    }
}
```

As noted above, I'd ideally like the deeply nested Segments to also bind to a LinkedHashMap but it's bound to a JSONArray.

Any suggestions how to get it bound to a LinkedHashMap as I'd like to avoid having to manipulate JSONArray in my service and thereby coupling my service with the JSON format.

If there's a way to do the conversion at the command level using a getter I'm all for that also.

thanks

EDIT:

Using

```
List zones = org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(), new org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory(ZoneCommand.class))
```

appears to work but the underlying objects are still JSON elements. I then tried using:

```
List<RateZoneCommand> zones = org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(), new org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory(ZoneCommand.class))
```

and at least I got an error indicating it trying to convert:

```
Validation error: ... org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray to required type java.util.List for property zones; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org..JSONObject] to required type [ZoneCommand] for property zones[0]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a command class for each level. Mark `Zone`- and `Segment`-command as `@Validateable`.

To your `GroupCommand`, add:

```
List zones = org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(), new org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory(ZoneCommand.class))
```

To your `ZoneCommand`, add:

```
List segments = org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(), new org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory(SegmentCommand.class))
```

In your form just use `group.zones[0].segments[0]`. If you change a field type of your command class, remember to restart the grails server.

Comment: Thanks for that. It almost works for me. However I'm seeing a weird problem at the third level deep. When trying to debug the segments (this is the third level) and using: `log.debug("${segments.class} and ${segments}")` the output for `.class` is `null` while the `segments` log statement shows me all the values. I can't understand why the class is null. When I try and bind the properties to `new Segment(segment.properties)` I get an `argument type mismatch`. I assume it's related to the `class` coming out as null. I'm not sure how to find the correct underlying type.

Comment: In the above I meant to say `segment` not the plural. The issue occurs when iterating over the segments.

Comment: After trying to call `hasErrors()` on the `segment` object I did get this exception ` org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject.hasErrors() ...` so it seems the segment is still a `JSONObject` rather than a `SegmentCommand`.

Comment: After much debugging it seems that although the answer above was very helpful it doesn't seem to instantiate the nested command objects. I get back JSONArray and JSONObject every time. My problem was confounded by the fact that it seems when passing a null id to another domain object in the JSON, loading the domain object fails with a cryptic `argument type mismatch` error. I think it's to do with how the converter is handing JSONNull for long numbers.

Comment: Sorry there was an error. It should have been `group.zones[0].segments[0]` instead of `group.zones[0].segment[0]`.