# Deep JSON serialization in Grails not working

Tags: json, grails

I have an object structure like so:

```
class Message {

   static mapWith="mongo"
   static embedded = ['to', 'author', 'comments', 'tags']

   ObjectId id
   Set<ObjectId> to
   Author author
   String text
   List<Comment> comments
   Set<String> tags
   Date postedOn
   Date lastEditOn
}

class Comment {
   Author author
   String text
   int thumbsUp = 0
   int thumbsDown = 0
   Date postedOn
   Date lastEditOn
}
```

And the following code for serialization to JSON

```
render Message.findStreamFor( session.user, groups, 0, 20 ) as JSON
```

However, none of the embedded collections are being serialized.  They are just missing.  I've tried adding the following to my Config.groovy to make it deeply serialize by default:

```
grails.converters.json.default.deep=true
```

But that doesn't seem to change anything.  I've seen the objects are populated from MongoDB in the debugger, but it just doesn't make it to the JSON serialized output.  How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Ok I've figured out a bit more by debugging the code.  Inside the DefaultGrailsDomainClass.getPersistentProperties() it doesn't return the collections as properties when called.  And JSON serializer never visits them.  On line 103 of DomainClassMarshaller is the call to getPersistentProperties which isn't returning all properties.

```
    GrailsDomainClassProperty[] properties = domainClass.getPersistentProperties();
```

Seems like this is a bug!  How has no one else ever found this?

Comment: Have you also tried using `JSON.use('deep')` before rendering instead of using the config property?

Comment: I get a compile error.  It doesn't know what use is.  I've seen people referring to that, but also lots of people saying that bad information.  Maybe a grails myth.  So I don't know what to trust.

Comment: [Source Code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/grails/converters/JSON.java#L421) has implementation of `use`.

Comment: I saw that after I typed that.  I put a call to that in BootStrap.groovy, and it still didn't change it.  I have registered two marshallers for Date and ObjectId as well.  I don't know if that has an impact on this.  I crawled the JSON data structure and see the DeepDomainClassMashaller registered.  I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Added an important update.  Collections are not returned from getPersistentProperties() so they just aren't seen.

Comment: They (JSONArray) are not parsed during data binding to domain objects either. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16826593/2051952) provided few days back.

Comment: I'm not sure how that applies to this discussion exactly, but I filed a bug because the logic is just plain wrong in JSON for embedded objects.  http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10175

Comment: What I was referring to is the converse of your problem which is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513416/grails-json-binding-to-linkedhashset-instead-of-jsonarray-for-deeply-nested-rela)

Answer (score 1):

You could to use [GSON plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gson). It didn't help me in a similar problem but it may help you.

This plugin was written to overcome nested object *deserialization* problem in standard Grails JSON converter, but it may also be better at *serializing* them.